# ¿Cómo guadar ruta completa en Firebase?

Tags: firebase

Siempre he tenido esta duda, tengo una ruta que constantemente estoy modificando, en `employee>` cuando realizo una modificacion mediante angularFire ejecuto `vm.employee.$save()` pero dentro de `employee` tambien existe un array `employee>bonosNomponibles` este no guarda las modificaciones, ¿por qué sucede esto?

[image: esta es mas o menos la estructura]

Comment: Hola Luis siempre se actualiza desde el nodo para abajo, podrias incuir el codigo que usas para poder buscar el error?

Comment: Ya lo solucione, mi problema era que hacia referecia antes al nodo bonosNoImponibles

Comment: Me alegro que hayas encontrado el error, por favor cierra la pregunta para que no figure más como no respondida.